# iOS App crashing at startup

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, crash, instrumentation

I tried to run my app in ipad 1 (iOS 5.0) but at the startup sometime app crashing(during  splash screen image) .So i run a profile check and then the total memory usage is near to 5.0Mb and it crashed during launch image .I got a alert from profile that "low memory" .Then i checked the memory allocation and i saw its also using 6.0 mb to get app open and then suddenly it drop to 4.0 Mb and after sometime app crashed.Please check the attached image along with this.

[image: Memory allocation check]

Comment: Have you tried to decet Zombie?

Comment: i have enabled zombie in scheme but i didnt saw zombie in profile tools

Comment: @Navi what operation you are performing after splash screen. Can you Explain bit because a 5 Mb image can not crash an app and when it is located in the bundle.

Comment: @SumitSharma yeah..actually it taking 5 news feed from web and trying to display but in iPad3 its working fine..

Comment: @Navi i think problem may be in the http Request. Which method you're using for News feed.NSurlConnection/NSOperationQueue/or some else

Comment: @SumitSharma i tried the same with break point ,put  a first break point on - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOp    ..  but its not reached there before itself app crashed

Comment: This may be a silly recommendation, but I had accidentally set Distribution profiles in my Code Signing / Provision Profiles instead of Development ones. Reset and it fixed my problem right away.

Answer (score 2):

When your app launches, `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` gets called. It is your job to return from this method as soon as possible. Only do strictly necessary things that your need for your app before your present something to the user.

Do not do ANY synchronous networking at this moment. You can kick off async calls to the network, but you have to return from this method immediately. If you do not, the system will kill your app before it even got to present it's first view.

Comment: i tried the same with break point ,put a first break point on - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOp .. but its not reached there before itself app crashed

Comment: When i'm doing profiling app crashing without executing any code. In normal running app going through viewdidload and crashing

Comment: Do you have a crash log?

Comment: There is nor crash log..thats the confusing thing..i didnt get any crash log.

Comment: am getting a memory warning ..then suddently it crashing